# Attic insulation

Tags: insulation

The insulation is falling down from my attic ceiling.  Can I staple rolled brown paper over it?  Or is there something else that I should use.  I would prefer not to replace the existing insulation

Comment: Pictures are always recommended.  But, in general, you don't put insulation against the roof of an attic ceiling.  The insulation belongs on the floor of the attic, against the ceiling below.

Comment: Insulation falling down in attic, sounds like a non living space.  Would place insulation on the floor to insulate the living space and add more.

Comment: Waiting for pics, but it would be an occasion to install a vapor barrier, which will also prevent air drafts

Comment: It sounds like you have batt insulation in that case If you have insulation right up against the roof decking ( The wood that your shingles are nailed to) It can cause problems with that wood. You have not indicated that there are channels. If there are disregard my info.
I am telling you this in the best interest of saving you from a damaged roof deck from trapped moisture. You need to place Styrofoam channels or something similar between the roof rafters before installing the insulation so the roof deck and "breathe". 1 to 2 inches of airspace is the common recommendation.
The string suggest

Answer (score 2):

There are commercial items available for this purpose- I have seen plastic mesh which is stapled to the underside of the wood. There are thin metal rods which you can wedge between studs or rafters that are made to hold insulation in.

I have found that when insulating raised wood framed floors it is sufficient to just staple string (like mason twine) across the wood members back and forth to keep the insulation from falling out.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Brown rolled paper is pretty thin and the heat will dry it out fast and you'll be in the same boat, attic, in a few years. I just wrapped twine back and forth the studs around big headed roofing nails.